# How to add rows with the same specifications as the ones in a tableWidget after a table is already created?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

In my app I enter a vlaue and said value sets the number of rows to the table. Within the function I will post here I do all the stuff related to setting up the TableWidget. What I want is to to be able to add new rows later on using the same method. Meaning, if I entered '3' and generated 3 rows, I want to be able to add more rows if I enter new values as well. In my UI I have a spin box to which I enter a value, this value is basically how many rows I want. Then I click a button and this function is called. This part is okay.

```
    void Pressurator::NozzleCount()
{
int nozzleCount = 0;
 int index = 0;
 nozzleCount = TabUI.nozzlesNum_SB->value();
 if(TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount() == 0){
     index = 0;
     TabUI.tableWidget->setRowCount(nozzleCount);
     qDebug()<<"NozzleCount: "<<nozzleCount<<"| Total Rows: "<<TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount();
 }else if(TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount() > 0){
     TabUI.tableWidget->setRowCount(TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount() + nozzleCount);
     index = TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount() - nozzleCount;
     qDebug()<<"NozzleCount: "<<nozzleCount<<"| Total Rows: "<<TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount();
     qDebug()<<"Index starts at: "<<index;
 }
 qDebug()<<"CHECK 1";


 for(int i=0; i<TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount(); i++){
     for(int j=0; j<TabUI.tableWidget->columnCount(); j++){
  TabUI.tableWidget->setItem(i,j, new QTableWidgetItem);
     }
 }
 qDebug()<<"CHECK 2";

 QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(parent);
        // Set validator
 QIntValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(0, 9, lineEdit);
        lineEdit->setValidator(validator);
 QStringList labels = {"Diameter(in)","Area(in²)","Type","Q(gpm)","DP(psi)"};
 TabUI.tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);

// QHeaderView* header = TabUI.tableWidget->horizontalHeader();
// header->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);

 qDebug()<<"CHECK 3";

 for(int i=0 ; i< nozzleCount; i++)
 {
// QDoubleSpinBox * ND_SB = new QDoubleSpinBox;
// QDoubleSpinBox * NA_SB = new QDoubleSpinBox;
 QComboBox * nozzleType = new QComboBox;


// ND_SB->setDecimals(5);ND_SB->setRange(0,500);
// NA_SB->setDecimals(5);NA_SB->setRange(0,500);
 nozzleType->addItems(nozzleTypesList);


// TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,0, ND_SB);
// TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,1, NA_SB);
 TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,2, nozzleType);
 qDebug()<<"CHECK 4";

 }
 qDebug()<<"CHECK 5";



 QObject::connect(TabUI.tableWidget, &QTableWidget::itemChanged, this, &Pressurator::CalculateDiameterORArea);

 qDebug()<<"CHECK 6";


}
```

The "CHECK # were debug messages I used to trace the problem that occurs for me. My app crashes at the first for loop at the top whenever I try enter a new value after the initial one that generates the table. I tried inserting an if statement that checks the table whether its rows are > 0 or not and if so any new value enter will translate to new rows added at the end of the table.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    void Pressurator::NozzleCount()
            {
             int nozzleCount = 0;
             nozzleCount = TabUI.nozzlesNum_SB->value();
            
            
             qDebug()<<"CHECK 1";
            
            
             
             qDebug()<<"CHECK 2";
            
             QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(parent);
                    // Set validator
             QIntValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(0, 9, lineEdit);
                    lineEdit->setValidator(validator);
             QStringList labels = {"Diameter(in)","Area(in²)","Type","Q(gpm)","DP(psi)"};
             TabUI.tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);
            
            // QHeaderView* header = TabUI.tableWidget->horizontalHeader();
            // header->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
            
             qDebug()<<"CHECK 3";
            
             for(int i=0 ; i< nozzleCount; i++)
             {
             TabUI.tableWidget->insertRow(TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount());
for(int j = 0 ; j < TabUI.tableWidget->columnCount();++j)
              TabUI.tableWidget->setItem(TabUI.tableWidget->rowCount() - 1,j, new QTableWidgetItem(""));
            // QDoubleSpinBox * ND_SB = new QDoubleSpinBox;
            // QDoubleSpinBox * NA_SB = new QDoubleSpinBox;
             QComboBox * nozzleType = new QComboBox;
            
            
            // ND_SB->setDecimals(5);ND_SB->setRange(0,500);
            // NA_SB->setDecimals(5);NA_SB->setRange(0,500);
             nozzleType->addItems(nozzleTypesList);
            
            
            // TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,0, ND_SB);
            // TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,1, NA_SB);
             TabUI.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,2, nozzleType);
             qDebug()<<"CHECK 4";
            
             }
             qDebug()<<"CHECK 5";
```

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: could you please reexplain what eactly you want to do?

Comment: Add new rows over the ones already added if the user chooses to. The Spin Box original sets the number of rows the user will work with. Should they enter another number after the first time, this will be new rows added to the table. Thing is the new rows cause the app to crash at the part where I call the *setItem* function

Comment: I also made an edit to the portion before the *Check1* message